# Return attribute of object, given string name of the attribute

Tags: python

Is something like this possible?

```
class MyObject(object):
    attr = 1

def fetch(ob, attr)
    return ob.attr

mo = MyObject()
print fetch(mo, 'attr') #any way to do this?
#expected 1
```

The reason I ask is because I do know the name of attribute I will be calling, and the object has quite a few attributes and so I could do a massive `if/elif` block, but that would be ugly and harder to maintain.

Comment: one of the way to store variables in dictionary

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, this is what [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function does.

```
def fetch(ob, attr)
    return getattr(ob, attr)
```

Obviously, you can just use `getattr` directly.

Comment: Of course, reimplementing `getattr` as `fetch` is rather superfluous…

Comment: Of course I'm not going to re-implement it, I will just use `getattr` =). The point was to show an easy to understand example @deceze.